# ASE/XTB: zero temperature and stress in MD simulation

Tags: molecular-dynamics, atomic-simulation-environment, stress-strain

I want to see how the volume and pressure of my cell is changing during a MD relaxation in ASE. I used the `atom.get_volume()` and `atom.get_stress()` to print out the values and figured out that they are not changing. I use a `FrechetCellFilter` to make sure the cell stress and atomic forces are minimised simultaneously.

Here's an example with a 2x2x2 Ang cell containing 4 molecules of H2, I am using the GFN1-xTB calculator and perform a NVT and NPT calculation.

There are a couple of points I can't figure out: why is the stress always a list of zeros? Is there any issue with the calculator? why does the temperature (and the kinetic energy) drop to zero in NPT?

Please find below the submission script, the input file and the output.

Thank you

Submission script:

```
""" Plot changing structure """

import ase
import numpy as np
from ase.md.npt import NPT
from ase.md.nvtberendsen import NVTBerendsen
from asap3 import Atoms, units
from xtb.ase.calculator import XTB
from ase.io.trajectory import Trajectory
from ase.filters import FrechetCellFilter

input_file = 'H2_box.xyz'
cell_size = 2

calculator = XTB(method="GFN1-xTB")

atoms = ase.io.read(input_file)
atoms.rattle(stdev=0.01)
atoms.set_cell(np.array([cell_size, cell_size, cell_size]))
atoms.set_pbc(True)
atoms.center(vacuum=1)
atoms.set_calculator(calculator)

ecf = FrechetCellFilter(atoms)

traj_file = 'H2_box.traj'
traj = Trajectory(traj_file, 'w', atoms)

def printenergy(a=atoms): # store a reference to atoms in the definition.
    """Function to print the potential, kinetic and total energy."""
    epot = a.get_potential_energy() / len(a)
    ekin = a.get_kinetic_energy() / len(a)
    vol = a.get_volume()
    stress = a.get_stress()
    print(f'Epot = {epot:3.3f}eV, '
          f'Ekin = {ekin:3.3f}eV, '
          f'Etot = {epot + ekin:3.3f}eV, '
          f'T = {ekin / (1.5 * units.kB):3.3f}, '
          f'Vol = {vol:3.3f}, '
          f'Stress =  {stress}')


print('NVTBerendsen')
dyn = NVTBerendsen(
    ecf.atoms,
    timestep=0.1*units.fs,
    temperature_K=300,
    taut=100*units.fs,
    trajectory=traj_file,
    logfile='NVT.log',
    )

dyn.attach(traj.write, interval=10)
dyn.attach(printenergy, interval=10)
dyn.run(50)

print('NPT')
dyn = NPT(
    ecf.atoms,
    ttime=1e-4,
    pfactor=1e-4,
    timestep=0.1*units.fs,
    temperature_K=300,
    externalstress=0.000101325 * units.GPa,
    trajectory=traj_file,
    logfile='NPT.log'
    )

dyn.attach(traj.write, interval=10)
dyn.attach(printenergy, interval=10)
dyn.run(50)

traj.close()
```

Output:

```
NVTBerendsen
Epot = -13.611eV, Ekin = 0.000eV, Etot = -13.611eV, T = 0.000, Vol = 62.059, Stress =  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
Epot = -13.670eV, Ekin = 0.059eV, Etot = -13.611eV, T = 456.917, Vol = 62.059, Stress =  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
Epot = -13.672eV, Ekin = 0.060eV, Etot = -13.611eV, T = 467.998, Vol = 62.059, Stress =  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
Epot = -13.629eV, Ekin = 0.018eV, Etot = -13.611eV, T = 139.689, Vol = 62.059, Stress =  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
Epot = -13.644eV, Ekin = 0.033eV, Etot = -13.611eV, T = 252.785, Vol = 62.059, Stress =  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
Epot = -13.705eV, Ekin = 0.094eV, Etot = -13.611eV, T = 724.094, Vol = 62.059, Stress =  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
NPT
Epot = -13.623eV, Ekin = 0.000eV, Etot = -13.623eV, T = 0.000, Vol = 77.121, Stress =  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
Epot = -13.427eV, Ekin = 0.000eV, Etot = -13.427eV, T = 0.000, Vol = 93.430, Stress =  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
Epot = -13.194eV, Ekin = 0.000eV, Etot = -13.194eV, T = 0.000, Vol = 111.016, Stress =  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
Epot = -12.951eV, Ekin = 0.000eV, Etot = -12.951eV, T = 0.000, Vol = 129.904, Stress =  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
Epot = -12.713eV, Ekin = 0.000eV, Etot = -12.713eV, T = 0.000, Vol = 150.113, Stress =  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
```

Input file: H2_box.xyz

```
           8
  Built with Packmol
  H            0.013589       -0.001149        1.023230
  H            0.000832        0.011254        0.323456
  H            0.051896        1.974564        0.714629
  H            0.370690        1.998602        0.091899
  H            1.944549        1.995178        2.000676
  H            1.963944        2.001188        1.300971
  H            1.933873        0.445614        0.043857
  H            1.974646        0.077936        0.638122
```

Comment: Thanks to @flokno for pointing out some previous errors.